# Getting shortcode attribute values and shortcode content with JavaScript regex

Tags: tinymce, regex, views

This is an example shortcode:

```
[boutique_banner title="Loyalty Program:" link="More" linkhref="/"]Earn 1 point for every $5 spent[/boutique_banner]
```

I have created a custom mce view to display this shortcode nicely in the backend editor. Now I'm working on the "edit" button when this shortcode is clicked.

I am trying to get all the attributes and the shortcode content, so I can display them when doing `editor.windowManager.open`

This is the working regex I have for getting the attributes:

```
var re = /([\w\-.:]+)\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"/g, values = {}, match;
while(match = re.exec(shortcode_string)){
   values[match[1]] = match[2]
}
```

But I'm a little stuck on getting the actual shortcode content, `[x]this stuff[/x]`

Is there an existing javascript shortcode parser in wordpress? I had a look through the gallery mce view to try and see how they handle shortcode attribute parsing but nothing stood out.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

found it.

```
var str = '[boutique_icon icon="phone"]1300 555 555<br />(07) 555 555[/boutique_icon]';

console.debug( wp.shortcode.next( 'boutique_icon', str ) );
```

Comment: Finished full code, here it is: https://github.com/dtbaker/wordpress-mce-view-and-shortcode-editor

Comment: Can you please  beef it up a little, maybe explain in few words what wp.shortcode.next does